# I build a calculator and I want to give error if they didn't type any number

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, numbers, calculator

Code works pretty well if you enter an actual number and operator and it actually gives u an error code if you enter an invalid operator but I want to give same error code with numbers but I dont know how I use python 3.9 help plz

```html
num1 = float(input('Enter First Number:'))
op = input('Enter operator:')
num2 = float(input('Enter Second Number:'))

if op == '+':
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == '*':
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == '/':
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print('enter an operator plz')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [try/catch](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/) statements and/or while loops around each step.

```
flag1,flag2,operator =True,True,True

while flag1:
    try:
        num1 = float(input('Enter first Number:'))
        flag1 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a valid first number please")
        
while operator:
    op = input('Enter operator:')
    if not (op=='+' or op =='-' or op =='*' or op=='/'):
        print('Enter a valid operator please')
    else:
        operator=False

while flag2:
    try:
        num2 = float(input('Enter second Number:'))
        flag2 = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a valid second number please")        

if op == '+':
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == '*':
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == '/':
     print(num1 / num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along the lines of this:

```
invalid = True

while invalid:
    try:
        num1 = float(input('Enter First Number:'))
        op = input('Enter operator:')
        num2 = float(input('Enter Second Number:'))
        invalid = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")

if op == '+':
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == '*':
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == '/':
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print('enter an operator plz')
```